# Cocreateinstance consuming high cpu

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using a LOGSERVICELib.dll exposed interface methods as logging method in main project. There is abc.h file in main project where it create instance of LOGSERVICELib.dll and uses it's exposed methods to log main project errors. I recently observed that it's making process too slow ,after profiling the code, I found that cocreate instance consuming high cpu along with other CStdio functions* why Cstdio funcitons taking high cpu time(70-80%)?

```
        Cstdiofile::Readstring()
        Cstdiofile::writeString()
        Cstdiofile::flush()


LogHelper.h( external .h file)

class LogHelper
{

public:
    LogHelper()
    {
        CoInitialize(NULL);
    };


    ~LogHelper()
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    };

    static void LogMessage(_bstr_t eventName, _bstr_t logFilePath, _bstr_t logFileName, _bstr_t message)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK ;

        try
        {
            CComPtr<LOGSERVICELib::ILogUtility> ILog;
            if(ILog == NULL)
            hr = ILog.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(LOGSERVICELib::LogUtility));

            if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            {
                hr = pILog->PostMessage( logFilePath, logFileName, eventName, message, L"", L"");           
            }
        }
        catch( _com_error& )
        {
            // forget it
        }


    }}

stdAfx.h(Main project)

#define LOG_THIS(x)     LogHelper::LogMessage( L"Service", _Module.m_bstrLogHelper, _Module.m_LogHelperLogFile, x)


Service.cpp:

void publish()
{
LOG_THIS("published new service");
}
```

Comment: 1) Define what you mean by "consuming high cpu". 2) Why the try-catch block? COM functions don't throw. They return the status of the operation.

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new instance of `ILog` for each message that you log.

Comment: If I am not wrong cocreateinstance is a singleton so isn't that take care of it even if someone try to create multiple instance? "consuming high cpu" :when I debug the code it was showing 100% of cpu consumed isn't that make process slow?

Comment: @RameshNimmala "_If I am not wrong cocreateinstance is a singleton_" Why do you think that? 1) You can create multiple instances, of a same CLSID. Think `class` in C++, and instance of a `class`. Can there ever be a single instance of a `class`? 2) Your `LogMessage` creates a `coclass`, and destroys it, at the end of it (destructor of `CComPtr` destroys it), on every call. If it's out-of-proc COM server - that may be very expensive to do. So, when profiling, did you look at the hit count, of `CoCreateInstance`, and did you look at total CPU usage, or average?

Comment: I looked at hit count and it was more than 20 times. total CPU usage varied between 80% to 100%. Is there any alternative to create instance once and use the methods several times? or Can I put cocreate instance in constructor?

Comment: @RameshNimmala Every time you call CoCreateInstance it creates an instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
        hr = ILog.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(LOGSERVICELib::LogUtility));
```

Clearly this code belongs in the constructor of `LogHelper`. Profiler guided optimization for the win, and you already used the profiler. Good for you. While you're at it, get rid of the `f(ILog == NULL)` altogether and move the declaration to your class constructor. This way the code that tries to create it always runs.

CComPtr auto-frees the object.

Unfortunately `LogMethod` is currently `static`. To fix the performance the available choices are refactor until it isn't `static` anymore or implement `LOGSERVICELib::LogUtility` yourself.

Comment: `CComPtr` has automatic clean up. It doesn't need explicit `Release`

Comment: You do not cast COM interfaces by using `dynamic_cast`. The COM-compatible equivalent of what you were trying to accomplish is `QueryInterface`. And, as noted, you don't need it anyway, since `CComPtr` is a smart pointer, that automatically releases the interface reference count on destruction.

Comment: @Joshua I updated code again can you please take a look at it? it's static method and I can't move or make  CComPtr<LOGSERVICELib::ILogUtility> ILog  as static that's really bad as per some articles. Do you have any suggest ions what would be the best solution?

Comment: @RameshNimmala: Unfortunately your choices are few.

Comment: @Joshua I updated it to non-static method as per your suggestion and try to access it in stdAfx.h(Main project) but I am struggling with declaring a macro. I tried to use  #define LOG_THIS(x)     extern LogMessage( L"Service", _Module.m_bstrLogHelper, _Module.m_LogHelperLogFile, x) but it did not work and also I have seen several articles and Microsoft link where they declared cocreateinstance inside the method instead of constructor. Can you please provide your insight on both macro declaration and cocreateinstance inside the method instead of constructor?

Comment: @RameshNimmala: You provided the incite that CoCreateInstance of this particular COM object is slow. I don't use macros like that and have nothing to add.